# get data from sqlite into edittext based on condition provided

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on an `Android` project where I am struck with a issue. I need to fetch data from `SQLite` `db` based on condition provided.

In precise I mean to say I need to get the data from `SQLite` where I provide condition an display that returned value in `EditText`.
Like:

```
SELECT SPECIALCHARCTER FROM <TABLENAME> WHERE POSITION = "0";
```

I need a good link to study this process. Can anyone please help me in issue.

You can check out sample code of [DBHelper.java class](http://pastebin.com/8NaunCnX).

I shall be very happy to see reply from u friends and help me in solving this issue.

Thanks & Regards,

Raghav

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is the good links to work with the sqlite with android with many controls

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/55.html

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/android-developer-tutorial-part-12.html

Answer (score 0):

Try select statement in the following way

```
SELECT * FROM  Contact where position LIKE '%"+0+"%'"
```

this may helps you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you code pasted is a mess as it is not good formatted and filled with code that is commented out. Hard to see anything.

What I saw was this code:

```
EditText result=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SPECIALCHARCTER FROM " + TABLE + " where POSITION = 0", null);
int A = c.getColumnIndex("POSITION");
String strRet;
strRet = c.getString(A);
results.setText("" + strRet);
c.moveToNext();
```

This will fail for multiple reasons:

1. Your cursor c is never moved to the first place before you access it. So it will always fail
2. Calling c.moveToNext() at the end of the method is senseless
3. Your variable results is never initialized

My advice: Remove every UI element from this class and start reading some links Pratik provided in his answer.